# PHP if else condition

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

somebody help me please,

```
<?php if ($_POST['jobs'] == 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 && $_POST['sex'] = 'L') {*true statement*} ?>
```

it is correct? CMIIW.
someone please explain how to write if else with array condition. Thanks

Comment: which value get in $_POST['jobs']

Comment: Use in_array function.

Comment: `$_POST['sex'] = 'L'` I'm assuming you meant double equals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd advise you to check out the [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

```
$jobs = array('6', '7', '8', '9');
if (in_array($_POST['jobs'], $jobs) && $_POST['sex'] == 'L')
{
    //Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<?php 
    $string="6 || 7 || 8 || 9";
    $newarray=explode('||',$string); // $newarray is like array('6', '7', '8', '9');
    if (in_array($_POST['jobs'],$newarray) && $_POST['sex'] == 'L') {*true statement*} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If $_POST['jobs'] contain only one value, make array with all expected results. After that you can use in_array function for checking whtr the value contains in that array or not.

```
$resultArray = array('6', '7', '7', '8');
if (in_array($_POST['jobs'], $resultArray ) && $_POST['sex'] == 'L')
{
   //true condition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this You have to give value each time when you use `||`

```
<?php if ($_POST['jobs'] == 6 || $_POST['jobs'] == 7 || $_POST['jobs'] ==8 
        || $_POST['jobs'] ==9 && $_POST['sex'] = 'L') {} 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used one equal sign instead of two here :

```
$_POST['sex'] = 'L'
```

so that the program always see the condition true and set value of $_POST['sex'] to 'L' .

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
$jobs = array(6, 7, 8, 9);

if ((in_array($_POST['jobs'], $jobs) && (strcmp($_POST['sex'], 'L') == 0)) {
    //Do super cool stuff
}
```